# Native linking failed in xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, brother-print-sdk

I am using a native sdk (BrotherPrinter sdk) in my xamarin project, but while building the xamarin.iOS project am getting "Native linking failed" errors.How to fix this please help me on this.

I did the following things but it didn't worked.

Tried with Linker behavior : Don't link, sdk only and Link all

Deleting obj and bin files.

Clean & Rebuild the solution.

For the error MT5209 I have changed the architecture , and I hope it will work in real devices.
These are the errors I am getting.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when the native linker cannot find an Objective-C class. You can add the **[Protocol]** attribute to the api that binds the Objective-C protocol for annotation, [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#:%7E:text=MT5211%3A%20Native%20linking%20failed%2C%20undefined%20Objective%2DC%20class%3A%20*.%20The%20symbol%20%27*%27%20could%20not%20be%20found%20in%20any%20of%20the%20libraries%20or%20frameworks%20linked%20with%20your%20application.) can help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply changing the supported architectures to just x86_64 from iOS properties. Double click iOS project to open iOS properties window and set like below. Clean and rebuild; error will be gone.

[image]